# How do I use OpenSSL in the terminal to convert a .pem file to other formats?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use OpenSSL in the terminal. I have installed OpenSSL using brew install openssl. I want to convert a .pem file to another format that my hosting provider will accept.

I have tried several different formulations of the code and plying the certificate from different places but none seem to work and all give me various error messages including permission denied.

This is what I tried last...

```
openssl pkcs12 -in /Users/myname/fullchain.pem -inkey /Users/myname/privkey.pem -out /Users/myname/fullchain.pfx -cacerts
```

This is my output

```
4552226412:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong tag:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.250.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1125:
4552226412:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.250.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:306:Type=PKCS12
```

What might this mean and what code should I be using?

Edit: I am getting output files but they are of course empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is usually when the certificate format you pass to the command is not what it is expecting. The following command should solve it for you.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out  /Users/myname/fullchain.pfx -inkey /Users/myname/privkey.pem -in /Users/myname/fullchain.pem
```

It should prompt you to enter an export password to encrypt the .pfx files content if it has succeeded.

Comment: I have tried this, the error I am now getting is as follows  `Error opening private key /Users/myname/privkey.pem
4516853356:error:02FFF00D:system library:func(4095):Permission denied:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.250.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:255:fopen('/Users/myname/privkey.pem', 'r')
4516853356:error:20FFF002:BIO routines:CRYPTO_internal:system lib:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.250.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:257:
unable to load private key`

Comment: Hi John. Looking at that error, it appears that the file permissions on your private key are preventing openssl from reading its contents to export into the pfx format. Can your user account open the private key in a notepad application? Try to change the permission on it temporarily ```chmod 644 /Users/myname/privkey.pem```

Comment: I used sudo instead and I now have an ecrypted certificate - yay! However now when I open the file I see jargon. I want to upload the certificate in text so I need the whole "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- etc" to be legible. Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: Unfortunately you won't get that from a pfx formatted file. If the hosting provider accepts pfx files, then you should be able to upload the file as a whole and supply them with the exported passphrase so they can extract the data.

Comment: I see. Well they didnt accept .pem and .pfx wont work given what you have just said. can you suggest another format that will show the certificate or a program I can use to see it?

Comment: The certificates you have already in the pem format can be opened in a normal text editor. In order to view the context of a pfx file in the same way, you need to extract the certificates back to pem format. Can I ask who the hosting provider is? Have they given reasons as to why they cannot accept the pfx and pems you're providing?

Comment: I am using ihostfull.com. It is hilarious what lengths these sites go to make you pay, I am trying to build a website and host it completely free. They give you a text box but dont accept .pem. or another one I found allowed me to set the A and AAAA records but did not let you get certificates from third parties so I am creating the certificate on that site and bringing it over to this one but now I am stuck on the text box as you now know. Anyway I have raised a ticket with the site and will see what they say regarding acceptable formats.

Comment: Update: they do not accepts free certificates made in OpenSSL. Thieves!